Separation of points studying closed ideals of $C(K)$
I was studying the closed ideals of $C(K)$ with $K$ a compact space (I assume, with the topology given by $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, since the Stone-Weierstrass theorem is applied, although my textbook does not say anything).
In general, given $F$ a closed subset of $K$ we denote as $I_F$ the ideal formed by the functions of $C(K)$ valued $0$ in $F$, it is, $I_F=\{f\in C(K):f|_F=0\}$. We write $I_x$ for $F=\{x\}$.
In this sense, let $I$ be an ideal of $C(K)$ and let $F:=\{x\in K : I\subset I_x \}$ being the set of the elements of $K$ for which it exists $f(x)=0$ $\forall f\in I$.
F is closed (this is ok so far).
Then, since $\forall x\in K\setminus F$ there exists $f\in I$ such that $f(x)\neq0$, the text stated that then we may infer that $I$ separates points of $K\setminus F$.
But why?

I am not quite sure what is unclear. By definition of $F$, if $x$ is not in $F$, there is a function in $I$ that does not vanish at this point. This is the same as saying that $I$ separates the points of $K \setminus F$.

@ThusleGadelankz For me, to separate poinsts means that for every $x, y \in K\setminus F$, there exists $f\in C(K)$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$.

Sorry, I meant 'it exists $f\in I$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$, that's what I understand for 'I separates points of $K\setminus F$.

Let $x, y \in K \setminus F$, $x \neq y$. Pick any $f \in I$ s.t. $f(x) \neq 0$. There are two cases:

$f(x) \neq f(y)$, in which case we’re done.
$f(x) = f(y)$. By Urysohn’s Lemma there is $g \in C(K)$ s.t. $g(x) \neq g(y)$. As $I$ is an ideal, $fg \in I$. Since $f(y) = f(x) \neq 0$ and $g(x) \neq g(y)$, we have $fg(x) \neq fg(y)$, so we’re done as well.


Thanks! Assuming that $K$ is normal, or a Hausdorff in addition to compact, I suppose.

@IAG You did mention Stone-Weierstrass theorem, which only applies to locally compact Hausdorff spaces.
